# how to combine two JavaPairRDDs by left key and right values

Tags: java, join, apache-spark

JavaPairRDD< String, Long > one:

> [(A, 0), (B, 0), (C, 0), (D, 0), (E, 0)... ]

JavaPairRDD< String, Long > two:

> [(B, 1), (C, 5), (D, 21)]

output should be:

> [(A, 0), (B, 1), (C, 5), (D, 21), (E, 0)... ]

To use values of second rdd based on keys of first rdd, *aggregateByKey*, *union*, *join* (left or right) methods were tried, but didn't work.

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Object> currentRdd = firstRdd.fullOuterJoin(secondRdd).map(stringTuple2Tuple2 -> new Tuple2<String, Long>(stringTuple2Tuple2._1(), stringTuple2Tuple2._2()._2().get()));
```

How can i combine two JavaPairRDD like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all the keys in `firstRdd` to be appear in the final result, or you just don't care about the keys that only appear in `secondRdd`, you should use 
`leftOuterJoin` instead of `fullOuterJoin`

`leftOuterJoin` explanation:

> Perform a left outer join of `this` and `other`. For each element (k, v) in `this`, the resulting RDD will either contain all pairs (k, (v, Some(w))) for w in `other`, or the pair (k, (v, None)) if no elements in `other` have key k.

Scala version:

```scala
val left = sc.parallelize(Array(("A", 0), ("B", 0), ("C", 0),("D", 0),("E", 0)))
val right = sc.parallelize(Array(("B", 1), ("C", 5), ("D", 21)))
val lojoin: RDD[(String, (Int, Option[Int]))] = left.leftOuterJoin(right)
val target = lojoin.mapValues(p => p._2.getOrElse(p._1))
target.foreach(println)
```

Java Version:

```
List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> left = new ArrayList<Tuple2<String, Integer>>();
left.add(new Tuple2<String, Integer>("A", 0));
left.add(new Tuple2<String, Integer>("B", 0));
left.add(new Tuple2<String, Integer>("C", 0));
left.add(new Tuple2<String, Integer>("D", 0));
left.add(new Tuple2<String, Integer>("E", 0));

List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> right = new ArrayList<Tuple2<String, Integer>>();
right.add(new Tuple2<String, Integer>("B", 1));
right.add(new Tuple2<String, Integer>("C", 5));
right.add(new Tuple2<String, Integer>("D", 21));

JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> leftRdd = sc.parallelizePairs(left);
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> rightRdd = sc.parallelizePairs(right);

JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<Integer, Optional<Integer>>> lojRdd = leftRdd.leftOuterJoin(rightRdd);

JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> result = lojRdd.mapValues(new Function<Tuple2<Integer, Optional<Integer>>, Integer>() {
  @Override
  public Integer call(Tuple2<Integer, Optional<Integer>> v1) throws Exception {
    return v1._2().or(v1._1());
  }
});

result.foreach(new VoidFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>>() {
  @Override
  public void call(Tuple2<String, Integer> t) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(t._1() + " " + t._2());
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there java any equivalent of *case(a,b)* in java? I couldn't find.

Comment: @Alp, Java counterpart added :)

Comment: thak you very much @Yijie Shen, *or()* method works:  `firstRdd.leftOuterJoin(secondRdd).mapValues(longOptionalTuple2 -> longOptionalTuple2._2().or(longOptionalTuple2._1()));`

Answer (score 1):

Requirement as per my understanding:
You have 2 RDD of same strucuture (Say: Id STR, value INT). You want all ID (from both RDDs) and value Summed up.

Next part assumes this requirement is correct. If not, do not bother reading, rather leave a comment instead with correct requirement :)

This is what I would suggest:

1. Union RDD1 and RDD2 (preferably both should be similarly partitioned based on ID so no shuffle needed here)
2. Turn unioned RDD to a dataFrame and register it as table (say, T)
3. write "Select id,sum(value) from T group by id"

This will work. In fact it is tried and tested process of loading data in RDBMS world when we combine multiple sources with similar strucutre.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is actually an **union** followed by a Sum **reduceByKey** fuctions.

```
JavaPairRDD< String, Long> result = one.union(two).reduceByKey((x, y) -> x+y);
```

Please refer to the docs for these functions.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html